# uncaught-error-java-net-connectexception: failed to connect to /192.168.1.2 (port 19000) from 192.168.1.5 (port 42176)

Tags: react-native, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am running react native project from WSL2.
I followed the steps in this blog https://hinty.io/devforth/how-to-install-wsl-2-best-way-to-run-real-linux-on-windows/ to install WSL and ubuntu.
and I enabled the CPU virtualization and windows server Linux feature,
then I installed node and yarn in WSL2.

To run the project:

- cd to project path
- set REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.2
- yarn start or expo start

when I open it from expo app on my mobile I have that error `uncaught-error-java-net-connectexception: failed to connect to /192.168.1.2 (port 19000) from 192.168.1.5 (port 42176)`
knowing that I already check my IP from cmd command ipconfig and the Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.2

Any help why I have that error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay for me the solution was to run a ps1 file from the administrator PowerShell. This file is used to:

- Delete old firewall rules it has created.
- Create new firewall rules for the port forwarding
- Delete all old port forwarding rules(if reset=1)
- Create/replace port forwarding rules based on WSL2's current IP address

Answer (score 0):

I got same error. and i changed on firewall configuration. i make all incoming request are allow and its has solved.